# Find $Cov(y_t(2),y_t)$

Tags: time-series, self-study, forecasting, arima, covariance

> Let the model $$y_t=y_ {t-1}-0.25y_{t-2}+\epsilon_t$$ where
>   $\epsilon_t$ is White Noise with mean zero and variance $\sigma^2$.
>
> a) Find the forecasts $y_t(1)$ and $y_t(2)$.
>
> b) Find $Cov(y_t(2),y_t)$. Express the result in function of
>   $Var(y_t)=\gamma(0)$.

This is an $AR(2)$ process with zero mean. In this notation $y_t(1)$ mean the forecast one-step ahead from $y_t$. What I did is

a) $$y_t(1)=E[y_{t+1}|y_1,\dots,y_t]=E[y_t-0.25y_{t-1}+\epsilon_{t+1}|y_1,\dots,y_t]$$
$$=y_t-0.25y_
{t-1}$$

$$y_t(2)=E[y_{t+2}|y_1,\dots,y_t]=E[y_{t+1}-0.25y_t+\epsilon_{t+2}|y_1,\dots,y_t]$$
$$=E[y_{t+1}|y_1,\dots,y_t]-0.25E[y_t|y_1,\dots,y_y]=y_t(1)-0.25y_t$$
$$=y_t-0.25y_{t-1}-0.25y_t=0.75y_t-0.25y_{t-1}$$

b) $$Cov(y_t(2),y_t)=Cov(0.75y_t-0.25y_{t-1},y_t)$$
$$=0.75Var(y_t)-0.25Cov(y_{t-1},y_t)=0.75\gamma(0)-0.25\gamma(-1)$$

Since $\gamma(-1)=\gamma(1)$ then

$$\gamma(1)=E[y_ty_{t-1}]=E[y_{t-1}y_{t-1}]-0.25E[y_{t-2}y_{t-1}]+E[\epsilon_t y_{t-1}]$$
$$\gamma(1)=\gamma(0)-0.25\gamma(1)\Rightarrow \gamma(1)=\frac{\gamma(0)}{1.25}$$

So

$$Cov(y_t(2),y_t)=0.75\gamma(0)-0.25\times \frac{\gamma(0)}{1.25}$$

This covariance is right?

Comment: Shouldn't $\gamma(1)=E[y_ty_{t-1}]-E(y_t)E(y_{t-1})$? I mean, that is what Covariance means.

Comment: @LandonCarter You are right, but it is a zero mean process I think, then the second part is zero.